# one-hot-encode list of words at the character level without looping over resulting tensor

Tags: python, torch, tensor

I want to implement a function that receives a list of words and returns a tensor

with the dimensions (#word,length of longest word,26)

the idea is to create a (length of longest word,26) tensor per each word where each row is filled with zeros and single one that represents the letter in that position. for example the word "abc"
will be represented by the following tensor:

```
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

each "row" (that represents a word) in the resulting tensor should be of the same size.
so I use padding of zero rows for each word.

for example, if we have the input list of word ["cd", "abc"]. the resulting tensor should be:

```
tensor([[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0]],
        [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0]]] dtype=torch.int32)
```

we assume that word are consisted only of lower case letters.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

def hot_one(words):
    max_l = max([len(i) for i in words]) #get length of longest word
    result = torch.empty((1,max_l, 26)).int() #create the resulting tensor
    for word in words:
        ints = (np.fromstring(word,dtype=np.uint8)-ord('a')) #create an array of latters value
        addition = np.zeros((max_l - ints.shape[0],)) -1  #padding for words that are shorter
        tr = torch.Tensor(np.expand_dims(np.hstack((ints,addition)),-1)) #create a tensor with the right dims
        tr = (tr[:] == torch.arange(26)).int() #this line converts to values of 1,0
        #result = torch.cat((result, tr)) #!!doesn't work!!#
    print(result)
```

the tricky part is that its not allowed to loop over the resulting tensor.
any ideas how this can be done?

edit: only allowed to use numpy and Torch functions

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `OneHotEncoder` from `sklearn`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: @RutgerMauritz Hi, forgot to mention that I only allowed to use numpy and torch